# Combining sets of medians and their deviation measures

Tags: standard-deviation, median

Suppose I have the following sets of estimates :

$S_i = \{ (m_1,d_1), (m_1,d_1), \ldots (m_{N_i},d_{N_i}) \}, i = 1,2,\ldots P $.

In each set, an ordered pair corresponds to median of a set of measurements and its corresponding median absolute deviation. Suppose I wish to determine the "mega-median" and its corresponding absolute deviation across all sets, i.e.

$(M,D) = \textrm{Mega-Median}(S_1,S_2,\ldots S_P)$

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: What's the definition of this "mega-median"? Do you just mean the overall median of the entire collection of data as if it were a single sample? If that's what you mean, there's no way to do it with only that information.

Comment: @Glen_b I want to find some meaningful way of combining the medians of pairs present in each set $S$ into a median value $M_S$ and its corresponding deviation $D_S$. Is there a principled way of combining this info ? Would things change if I know the number of samples used to obtain each $(m_i,d_i) \in S, i = 1,2 \ldots N_i$ ?